# Angular, which element should I disallow from the web crawlers

Tags: angular, web-crawler, robots.txt

I would like to use a `robots.txt` file to exclude useless element from the web crawlers.

But I don't know which element is "safe" to put in the disallow list.

Does somebody have a "standard" that he use on every project ?

*I've already kind of asked this question on the [ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138495/should-i-exclude-the-assets-folder-from-search-engine-crawlers-in-angular) website, but maybe stackoverflow is a better place for that.*

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se] and not cross-posted here.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller As written, I do already have posted similar question on the `webmasters` channel. I do have had responses and the question is closed. But I'm now wondering, in the angular dev perspective what the people are doing.